# Python - How can I annotate that a function has the same parameters as another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Context here is overwriting the method of a Class from a library

```py
from mail_library import MailClient

class LocalMailClient(MailClient):
    def send(**kwargs: KwargsFrom[MailClient.send]):
       print(f'Mocking email to {kwargs["recipients"]}')
```

Is there something similar to the `KwargsFrom` I suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

Define the type in a variable in the parent file, then import it

```
MAILCLIENT_SEND_RETURN_TYPE = List[int]
class MailClient:
    def send(**kwargs: MAILCLIENT_SEND_RETURN_TYPE):
        print(f'Mocking email to {kwargs["recipients"]}')
```

```
from mail_library import MailClient, MAILCLIENT_SEND_RETURN_TYPE
class LocalMailClient(MailClient):
    def send(**kwargs: MAILCLIENT_SEND_RETURN_TYPE):
        print(f'Mocking email to {kwargs["recipients"]}')
```